# Нужно переформатировать массив, который содержит пустые ключи но при этом имеет значения

Tags: php, массивы

Есть массив:

```
[heals_data] => Array
    (
        [] => Array
            (
                [scan_heals_data] => b322d23ed44560b6d988b6eea11a1c34.jpg
            )

        [0] => Array
            (
                [what_diseases] => болен
                [conclusion_date] => 8,51555444
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [what_diseases] => здоров
                [conclusion_date] => 43534535444
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [what_diseases] => неизвестно
                [conclusion_date] => 76887
            )
    )
```

Нужно изменить его формат так, чтобы на место пустого ключа `[]` встал ключ из его значения то есть `[scan_heals_data]`

Заранее я не знаю какие массивы есть внутри пустого ключа и какие ключи есть у этих внутренних массивов.

На выходе должен получиться массив вот такого вида:

```
[heals_data] => Array
    (
        [scan_heals_data] => b322d23ed44560b6d988b6eea11a1c34.jpg

        [0] => Array
            (
                [what_diseases] => болен
                [conclusion_date] => 8,51555444
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [what_diseases] => здоров
                [conclusion_date] => 43534535444
            )
        [3] => Array
            (
                [what_diseases] => неизвестно
                [conclusion_date] => 76887
            )
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$heals_data = Array
(
    '' => Array
        (
            'scan_heals_data' => 'b322d23ed44560b6d988b6eea11a1c34.jpg'
        ),
    0 => Array
        (
            'what_diseases' => 'болен',
            'conclusion_date' => 8,51555444
        ),
    1 => Array
        (
            'what_diseases' => 'здоров',
            'conclusion_date' => 43534535444
        ),
    3 => Array
        (
            'what_diseases' => 'неизвестно',
            'conclusion_date' => 76887
        ),
);


$result = array();
foreach ($heals_data as $key => $value) {
    if (empty($key) && ($key != '0')) {
        $result[key($value)] = $value[key($value)];
    } else {
        $result[$key] = $value;
        // array_push($result, $value); - либо так
    }
}

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Мне кажется, или результат не такой?

Comment: @Let'ssayPie нулик надо было просто в скобочки взять, подправил